# Pip install with pip in requirements

Tags: python-2.7, pip, setuptools

I made a package (called "my_package" in the following) that needs minimal versions of pip and setuptools to install. Is it possible to update them during the "pip install my_package" (but not by doing "pip install -U pip" before installing my_package)? I tryied to add them in the requirements but I end with the following exception:

```
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 1.5.6 (~/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip>=9.0.0'))
```

My setup.py is as follow:

```
from setuptools import setup

package_name = 'my_package'

requires = [
    'pip >= 9.0.0',
    'setuptools >= 36.0.0'
]


setup(name=package_name,
      author="Me",
      use_scm_version=True,
      packages=[package_name],
      zip_safe=False,
      setup_requires=['setuptools_scm'] + requires,
      install_requires=requires)
```

Thanks

**SOLUTION 1:**
It does not solve my issue but it makes it more explicit to the user:

```
from pkg_resources import get_distribution, parse_version

if parse_version(get_distribution('pip').version) < parse_version('9.0.0'):
    raise ImportError('The pip version is too old, please update it using the following command: pip install -U pip')

if parse_version(get_distribution('setuptools').version) < parse_version('36.0.0'):
    raise ImportError('The setuptools version is too old, please update it using the following command: pip install -U setuptools')
```

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Comment: Yes, thanks! It helped me to understand why it is hard to do :)

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade `pip` version:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Yes I know it can be done this way but is it possible to do it automatically when I install my_package ? (I am going to edit my question to make it clearer)

Answer (score 0):

You can start your `setup.py` code with upgrade command to `pip`, then reload and continue as usual.
**If there are still issues, try to use subscript around it.**

For example(use `os` or `subprocess` module):

```
import os
import pip
import importlib
from setuptools import setup

# duplicate this part to another script then reload.
os.system("python -m pip install -U pip")
# Python 3
importlib.reload(pip)
importlib.reload(setuptools)
# Python 2
reload(pip)
reload(setuptools)

package_name = 'my_package'

requires = [
    'pip >= 9.0.0',
    'setuptools >= 36.0.0'
]


setup(name=package_name,
      author="Me",
      use_scm_version=True,
      packages=[package_name],
      zip_safe=False,
      setup_requires=['setuptools_scm'] + requires,
      install_requires=requires)
```

**Upgrading pip**

On Linux or macOS:

```
pip install -U pip
```

On Windows:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the package is updated in the system but not in the current running instance. This makes me realize that there might not be a simple solution to solve this issue :/ I added a solution in my question that just raises explicit exceptions when the versions are not suitable.

Comment: where the current running instance is running ?

Comment: The instance of pip runned by "pip install my_package". As far as I understand the setup process, this instance calls 'os.system("python -m pip install -U pip")' but is not replaced by the newly updated pip. So I still get the "pkg_resources.VersionConflict" exception during installation.

Comment: Oh gotcha, maybe you can use reload on pip module. I will update my answer soon.

Comment: @StormRider Test it now

Comment: Still the same :/

Comment: My next step is to create subscript that work around this issue.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, calling a sub script might work but do you have something simple in mind? Because I would like to avoid labyrinthine solutions :)